# Design Search service using elastic search

Tags: rest, web-services, elasticsearch, design-patterns

I have a requirement. I am building up a search service for a social network. The search service should return the name of the users that somebody searches. Now it will be limited to user domain search only. I am planning to use elastic search to keep the indexes(user domain details). I will then call the EL from my search service(The search service is on nodejs). I am not able to think of a design on how to create the indexes for EL. Should I use a batch to create the indexes or during creation of users I will create the index.

A good pointers or a good design will be appreciated.

Comment: Depends on user experience, should they be searchable immediately after creating account then you'll have to do during registration time.

Answer (score 0):

you should create index when new user create

simple example may be useful

your user data like:
`

```
[
 {
    "_id": "1",
    "status": true,
    "username": "mak",
    "userdomain": "mydomain.com",
    "name": "mak doe"
 },
 {
    "_id": "2",
    "status": true,
    "username": "janny",
    "userdomain": "mydomain.com",
    "name": "janny"
 },
 {
    "_id": "3",
    "status": true,
    "username": "mac",
    "userdomain": "newdomain.com",
    "name": "mac peter"
 },
 {
    "_id": "4",
    "status": true,
    "username": "mak",
    "userdomain": "mydomain.com",
    "name": "mak peter"
 },
 {
       "id": "5",            
       "status": true,
       "username": "mak",
       "userdomain": "newdomain.com",
       "name": "mak peter"
 },
]
```

`

elastic schema look like as below:
`

```
PUT socialdata
{
    "mappings": {
          "users": {
         "properties": {
            "status": {
               "type": "boolean"
            },
            "name": {
               "type": "text"
            },
            "username": {
               "type": "string",
               "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "analyzer": "keyword_lowercase_analyzer"
                  },
                  "english": {
                     "type": "text",
                     "analyzer": "english"
                  }
               }
            },
            "userdomain": {
               "type": "string",
               "fields": {
                  "raw": {
                     "type": "string",
                     "analyzer": "keyword_lowercase_analyzer"
                  },
                  "english": {
                     "type": "text",
                     "analyzer": "english"
                  }
               }
            }
        }
       }
    }
}
```

`

For Bulk upload : 
`

```
POST socialdata/users/_bulk
{ "index": { "_index": "socialdata","_type": "users", "_id": 1 }}
{"status":true,"username": "mak","userdomain": "mydomain.com","name": "mak doe"}
{ "index": { "_index": "socialdata","_type": "users", "_id": 2 }}
{"status":true,"username": "janny","userdomain": "mydomain.com","name": "janny"}
{ "index": { "_index": "socialdata","_type": "users", "_id": 3 }}
{"status":true,"username": "mac","userdomain": "newdomain.com","name": "mac peter"}
{ "index": { "_index": "socialdata","_type": "users", "_id": 4 }}
{"status":true,"username": "mak","userdomain": "mydomain.com","name": "mak peter"}
{ "index": { "_index": "socialdata","_type": "users", "_id": 5 }}
{"status":true,"username": "mak","userdomain": "newdomain.com","name": "mak peter"}
```

`

for single index:
`

```
POST socialdata/users/_bulk
{ "index": { "_index": "socialdata","_type": "users", "_id": 1 }}
{"status":true,"username": "mak","userdomain": "mydomain.com","name": "mak doe"}
```

`

elastic query :
it will return only two record
`

```
POST socialdata/users/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "username": "mak"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "userdomain": "mydomain.com"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`

it will return only one record
`

```
POST socialdata/users/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "username": "mak"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "userdomain": "newdomain.com"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

`